# My Validation method is working inversely and I can't seem to correct it

Tags: angular, typescript

So I am doing a tutorial that is having me make an asynchronous validator. The form includes a section to look up retail stores by an id code. My validator is meant to let the user know if the id code that they enter does not exist.

```js
checkBranch(id:string): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.http.get(this.shopUrl+'/branches')
      .pipe(
         map((branchIdList: Array<any>) =>
               branchIdList.filter(branchId => branchId.id === id)
         ), 
         map(id => !id.length), 
         catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

when I enter the above code, I get an alert for only id codes in the database that I have. This is opposite of what I would like.

```js
checkBranch(id:string): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.http.get(this.shopUrl+'/branches')
      .pipe(
         map(( branchIdList: Array<any>) =>
            branchIdList.filter(branchId => branchId.id !== id)
         ), 
         map(id => !id.length), 
         catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

When I make this change, I get an alert for all codes entered into the form. How can I fix my code to get an alert for id codes that do not exist.

Comment: The second form looks correct, you filter out the ones that don't match what you have in the backend. If you get an alert for all codes, is it possible that all codes are missing from the backend?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make small changes in your code to better readability but the most important thing is you can share with us the
Api response

```
checkBranch(id:string): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.http.get(this.shopUrl+'/branches')
    .pipe(
       map((branchIdList: Array<string>) =>
         branchIdList.filter(branchId => branchId.id === id)
       ), 
       tap(branchIdList: Array<string> => branchIdList.length > 0), 
       catchError(this.handleError)
);
```